# Ripple animation with a border

Tags: android, animation, border, ripple

I want a create a ripple effect for a button like in the image below. I mean the effect on right arrow button click before drawing the circle and moving the line outside. The ripple effect has a circular border: How can I achieve this?

I tried setting stroke width for the ripple item, but has no effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:color="#40000000"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>

            <corners android:radius="50dp"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>


</ripple>
```

[image]